# Permissions issue using hard drive

Tags: python, linux, windows, permissions

I am new to using raspberry pi.
I've wrote a script in python that takes images and stores them in a connected hard drive, in a directory that is created by the script. When trying to open the files in another computer (windows) it says that I don't have access permission.
I have tried changing the permission of the files to be 777 and all corresponding directories sadly it did not help.
When using bash to see the permissions of the hard drive on the other computer I get question marks in the permission column.
[image]

Comment: Which filesystem are you using?  Windows does not understand Linux filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Windows to read a file you've written from a Python script (***presumably*** from your RPi OS), then you must be sure you write it to a **filesystem** that Windows can read, or use Samba to "translate".

You have (at least) two choices:

1. Create a partition on your ***"connected hard drive"***, and format it using FAT32. FAT32 is understood by Windows **and** Linux.
2. Set up a Samba server on your RPi to serve the ***"connected hard drive"***. You'll need to make sure you've properly declared your ***share*** in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

I've made [some notes on setup & config of a Samba server](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md) that may be helpful to you. My client is macOS, but not too different from Windows in this respect.